# How to handle back button android to both exit app and close react native navigation side menu when it is open in home page

Tags: back-button, wix-react-native-navigation, side-menu

I am using react native navigation Wix side menu in my project. I want to close it when It is open and user clicks on mobile physical back icon. But I have defined for the back button to close my app when user clicks on it. So my back icon should do two following works:

1- it should close the menu when it is open.
2- it should exit from app when the menu is close.

I have saved the status of the side menu (open: true , close:false) in  redux store to handle it. But the problem is when user open or close the menu with swiping on mobile screen. In this case I cannot update my state in redux store. I cannot disable this option (Swiping) of side menu in react native navigation to get ride of the problem. So I do not know how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the `componentDidAppear` event in your Side menu screen to set your redux store state for its visibility.

Also you could add `Backhandler` event handler in your screen to either close the side menu or exit the app.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
    if (reduxStore.sideMenuOpened) {
      // Close the side menu.
      closeSideMenu()
      // Prevent the Backhandler's event bubbling up.
      return true
    }
    // Let the backhandler's event bubble up to close the app if you are in root screen.
    return false
  })
}, [])
```